# how can I set only a specific browser like chrome, to use all the 100% bandwidth? windows xp

Tags: windows, browser, bandwidth

how can I set only a specific browser like chrome, to use all the 100% bandwidth? windows xp.

Is there any method to direct the internet only for a specific browser or application?

I also want to know any program which can display the programs actively using internet downloading and uploading in Kbs. so that i can verify, which is using how much bandwidth.

Comment: you should read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first to know what questions are supposed to be asked here...

Answer (score 0):

Setup an out bound firewall block that only allows Chrome to connect out.  Had this been Windows Vista or 7 you could have done it with the Windows Firewall, but in XP you need to find a 3rd party product to do outbound blocks.